# React conditional rendering causes multiple api calls

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I am using React + Redux + Redux-Saga.

In my scenario I am calling 2 apis - for Config and for Data (after Config fetched)

I am having issue when calling for Data. To make the story short:

This is working:

TestRoute.jsx file (not using `isConfig` yet):

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import TestComponent from '../components/Test';

const Test = ({ isConfig }) => <div>
  <TestComponent />
  <TestComponent />
  <TestComponent />
  <TestComponent />
</div>

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isConfig: !!state.config.payload.tenantId
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Test);
```

TestComponent.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { dataRequestInit } from '../state/actions/data';

class Test extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dataRequestInit('https://data/api/url');
  }

  render() {
    return <p>hello</p>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { dataRequestInit }
)(Test);
```

Saga file:

```
const getIsFetching = (state, url) => state.data.isFetching.includes(url);

function* fetchData(url) {
  try {
    const isFetching = yield select(getIsFetching, url);

    if (!isFetching) {
      yield put(actions.fetchDataIsFetching(url));

      const response = yield call(api, url);

      console.log('response', response);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('handle error', err);
  }
}

export default function* DataSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(actionTypes.FETCH_DATA_INIT, fetchData);
}
```

In this case all good - first call sets isFetching and one api request is being performed.
[Redux DevTools view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9f8K.png)

But if I recreate my Route file to start using isConfig flag and render TestComponents conditionally:

```
const Test = ({ isConfig }) =>
  isConfig && (
    <div>
      <TestComponent />
      <TestComponent />
      <TestComponent />
      <TestComponent />
    </div>
  );
```

Everything is going crazy and 4 api calls are going to server. That is because at first  4x DATA/FETCH_INIT and later 4x DATA/SET_IS_FETCHING actions are launched [Redux DevTools view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LPXf.png) instead of expected: 1x DATA/FETCH_INIT 1x DATA/SET_IS_FETCHING 3x DATA/FETCH_INIT like previously.

Can someone please explain to me why that is happening? What I am missing here and possibly how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I can see your problem, you are mounting the same component 4 times, see below:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.dataRequestInit('https://data/api/url');
}
```

And then you render that 4 times:

```
  <TestComponent />
  <TestComponent />
  <TestComponent />
  <TestComponent />
```

This will fire a separate instance of the function call for each component, having a variable for "isFetching" won't stop the others from making their API calls.

Another important thing to note, if this component needs to be rendered 4 times, and they all need the same data, it would be better to hand off control to the parent component, fetch the data once, and pass it down to your component in each instance, like this:

```
<TestComponent data={state.data}/>
```

Also, your reducer case for this action should look something like this:

```
switch (action.type) {
  case AUTH_REQUEST:
    return {
      ...state
    }
```

The state variable with spread operator, it was keeps the state from previous actions, in your case the is fetching variable.

Hope this helps

Lloyd

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer, but in my case isFetching is in Redux Store (I should highlight that at the first place, sorry), so it is common for all the components. Isn't it?

Comment: No it won't work like that, the data fetch init action will be fired 4 times, as this is fired every time you run a dispatch, it does not care about state at this point, also please share your reducer code, if you don't set up reducer correctly, your fetch init action will actually clear it every call, so you end up with 4 API calls as well.